# Android InAppBillingV3 purchase and check if the item was purchesed

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

I'm programming an Android app that's free. With an InApp purchase you can unlock additional features once.
I am using InAppBillingV3 to use this.

Im am creating the billing processor in my activity

```
 try {
        bp = BillingProcessor(this,"...",this)
        bp!!.initialize()
    } catch(e:Exception) {
        Log.e(Utils.LOG_TAG, e.message, e)
    }
```

And I purchase my item

```
fun purchaseProversion () : Boolean {
    try {
        if(inAppServiceAvailable()) {
            return bp!!.purchase(this, PROVERSION_PLAY_STORE_ID)
        }
    } catch(e:Exception) {
        Log.e(Utils.LOG_TAG, e.message, e)
    }
    return false
}
```

I hope that's all correct so far.

For test reason im am using "android.test.purchased" as PROVERSION_PLAY_STORE_ID

I would like to check if the proversion has already been purchased when the user clicks the button.
Something like:

```
fun startProFeature() {
    if(proversionAlreadyPurchased()) {
        // start feature
    } else {
        // show dialog that the user needs the proversion
        purchaseProversion()
    }
}

fun proversionAlreadyPurchased() : Boolean {
    // TODO TBD
    return false
}
```

What is the recommended way to implement this? (method: proversionAlreadyPurchased)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my working solution

```
 bp!!.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()
            var ownedProducts = bp!!.listOwnedProducts()
            if(ownedProducts != null) {
                var found = ownedProducts.find { it == PROVERSION_PLAY_STORE_ID }
                var proversion = found != null
```